# Can I use polymorph to turn people into creatures that aren't in the books?

Tags: dnd-5e, polymorph, animals

I'd like my gnome wizard to be able to turn people (and monsters) into bunny rabbits. But there aren't stats for that in either the player's hand book or the monster manual. There are stats for frogs (which can also be used for toads), but there isn't for rabbits for some reason.

Yes, I know you can make custom monsters, but I don't think the DM would be too keen on coming up with stats for something that wouldn't normally come up. And not bothering with stats may not be a good idea either. Everything needs at least a movement speed, AC, and hp. Otherwise, the *[polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph)* spell would essentially just be a more powerful version of hold person/monster. Also, if you play in the 'league' I believe it's called, you're not allowed to use any homebrew content anyway.

So, can I use polymorph to turn people into creatures that aren't in the books?

Comment: Are you actually asking about Adventurers League rules or was that just an example?

Answer (score 15):

## Only if your DM is happy with custom monsters

As you have mentioned, there are no stats for rabbits. Therefore, if your DM is unwilling to stat up a rabbit, you have two options; either reskin something like a [frog](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/frog) (minus its ***Amphibious*** trait) so that, mechanically, it's a frog, but you can call it a rabbit from a narrative perspective.

The other option is to change the beast you intend to *[polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph)* other creatures into, such as a frog, although this may harm the characterisation of your PC depending on how important that is it for it to be rabbits specifically.

## However, Tomb of Annihilation has something

The ToA adventure has an [Almiraj](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/almiraj), which is a CR 0 horned rabbit. If you DM is happy to use these stats, and just describe it without the horn, then that's the closest thing you're going to get to a rabbit.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

## This is going to depend on your DM

> The spell transforms a creature that you can see within range into a new form. [...] The target's game statistics, including mental ability scores, are replaced by the statistics of the chosen beast.

Nothing in the rules or the description for the spell explicitly restrict the form you choose to be already in the book specifically. However, no matter what form you choose, statistics are needed for it.

#### There's more than one way to (re)skin a rabbit

Thus, it will depend on how your DM wants to handle it.

One way would be to simply reskin another creature into a rabbit. As you suggest, a toad is a good candidate here possibly. There is actually the [almiraj](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/almiraj) listed in Tomb of Annihilation which is essentially just a horned rabbit as well. This has the advantage of giving the player what they want with minimal effort on the part of the DM.

Otherwise, the only option for the DM is to simply tell you that you can only choose from creatures in the book. This is ultimately easier on the DM in the end, but not nearly as fun for the player.

Given the diversity of creatures listed in the various D&D books, I have found no issues reskinning creatures to meet my players' needs and it has led to fun results. I would recommend taking this strategy whenever possible.

Answer (score 5):

## Yes, but just re-skinning

tl;dr So long as the DM can use a stat block for an existing beast, describing it as a different animal should work.

### Any Beast

In the books there are a list of beasts.  If the DM has additional beasts with stat blocks, those would be *fair game* so long as the state block has a CR to satisfy the spell's requirement:

> The new form can be any beast whose challenge rating is equal to or less than the target’s

### Rabbits

The GM could choose an animal stat block of similar sized creature such as weasel or cat.

### Smooth Gameplay and Storytelling

The player states what the character does, and the DM describes the outcome.  If the spell fails because "rabbits" aren't valid beasts to turn the target into, then that is what happens.  To facilitate smooth game play and story telling, it is advisable to give notice about it instead of surprising your fellow GM and Players with edge cases.